# Compiler keeps telling on "'object' has not been declared"...?

Tags: c++, include, getter-setter

See the code below :

**obj1.h**

```
class OBJ1 : public A_OBJ
{
  public:
    //virtual pure from A_OBJ
    virtual void m_method();

    int getterX();

  private:
    int x;
}
```

**obj2.h**

```
class OBJ2 : public A_OBJ
{
  public:
    //virtual pure from A_OBJ
    virtual void m_method();

    void iWantX();
}
```

**obj1.cpp**

```
#include "obj1.h"

OBJ1 obj1;

OBJ1::m_method()
{
  //do_something()
}
OBJ1::getterX()
{
  return x;
}
```

**obj2.cpp**

```
#include "obj2.h"

OBJ2 obj2;

OBJ2::m_method()
{
  //do_something()
}
OBJ2::iWantX()
{
  int z = OBJ1::getterX();
}
```

When I try to compile that simple code (`g++ obj1.cpp obj2.cpp _main_`), i keep getting an annoying error :

`obj2.cpp: error: 'OBJ1' has not been declared`

I already tried to declare `OBJ1 obj1` in `obj2.cpp` and other things, nothing worked...

Do you know how to fix this ? Thanks !

Comment: Where did you get the idea from to put header files on the compiler command line?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I did not, it's a mistake. Post edited.

Comment: @Patouf Looks like you not very honest with us :) You not provide full error log. Because you've missed ; after class definition. And when you defines method in obj1.cpp you've missed return type for OBJ1::m_method()

Comment: @Sergey it's a typo, syntax is correct :) I gave you the full error log (the single line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple

```
#include "obj1.h"
```

in `obj2.cpp`.

After this, the following will generate an error:

```
int z = OBJ1::getterX();
```

because `getterX` is not `static`. Either make it `static`, or call it on an instance of the class.

Bottom line: learn C++ from a book.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure I've already tried this one... Thanks for your help.

Comment: + 1 for the bottom line. He missed semicolon in class definition, so error log should be bigger.

Comment: `invalid us of member 'namespace::OBJ1::x' in static member function` :(

Comment: @Patouf did you miss "After this, the following will generate an error:"?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore no, `getter()` is now `static`.

Comment: @Patouf is `x` also static? Do you know what static means?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yup, i know what static means lol.As far as I recall, x must be static here, but when it is, i cannot use it anymore on its original class (like `x++;`). is there something i'm missing ?

Comment: @Patouf yes. You think you know what static means, but you don't - otherwise this behavior wouldn't surprise you. From static members, you can only call other static method or access other static members.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore is there any way to use `int x` in its original class **and** in the `static int getter()` method without compilation error ?

Comment: @Patouf make `x` static. You can still access it in the class.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore when `x` is `static`, i get weird `undefined reference to 'namespace::OBJ1::x'` errors. Even for the `return x;` in `static int getter()` ! And I'm not hiding anything, the code used is the one shown in my question.